# paperclip possible to specify single hash for different styles (thumbnail / original)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have the following model and would like my files to be uploaded like so:

```
/images/1/123abc_name_original.jpg
/images/1/123abc_name_medium.jpg
/images/1/123abc_name_thumb.jpg
```

If I used as below, the :hash is different for each file; I'd like this to be the same and be able to save it to database in my asset table. I am not that concerned about security of file.

code:

```
 Paperclip.interpolates :global_path  do |attachment, style|
     attachment.instance.assetable.global_id
  end

  Paperclip.interpolates :val  do |attachment, style|
    jt=:basename
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(jt)
  end


has_attached_file :asset, 
  :hash_secret => "jtsomething",
  :url => "/images/:global_path/:hash_:basename_:style.:extension",
  :path => UPLOAD_PATH + "/:global_path/:hash_:basename_:style.:extension",
  :styles => { :medium => "200x200>", :thumb => "75x75>", :bigthumb => "125x125"  

  }
```

even a consistent timestamp would be great like this:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :my_hash  do |attachment, style|
  Time.now.to_i.to_s
end
```

For different styles, paperclip will take different timestamp. It should be consistent.

I'm probably missing something on how to do this.

thx

Comment: What is your definition for the :hash interpolation?

Comment: there's a default :hash value which works in paperclip (and uses the :hash_secret value). Even if I override, the different instances will have different values (analagous to the Timestamp example provided later). Hoping to find someone who has gotten through this before.

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?  If you have the object id in the directory structure of the path you don't need to inject a hash into the filename.

Comment: the hash is more secure

Answer (score 0):

The default :hash_data is:

`:hash_data=>":class/:attachment/:id/:style/:updated_at"`

So override this option and remove `:style` and `:updated_at`. Then your hash should produce the same value for the different styles.